# C# Mock IHttpclient & CreateClient

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit

I have a function that I want to x-unit test, but it seems that I have to mock the CreateClient function? Whenever I debug it during testing it seems that the var client is equals to null. I am injecting the dependencies properly, I am sure of that. What I want to know is how to mock the CreateClient.

here is that function:

```
    public async Task CreateMessageHistoryAsync(Message message)
    {
        //This seems to be giving a null value
        var client = this.clientFactory.CreateClient(NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB);

        var formatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
        formatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();            

        var response = await client.PutAsync(id.ToString(), message, formatter);

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            throw new HttpRequestException(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        }
    }
```

here is the unit test, I am mocking the IHttpClient in a separate class and I am using that class.

```
    [Collection("MockStateCollection")]
    public class CreateMessageHistory
    {
        private readonly MockStateFixture mockStateFixture;

        public CreateMessageHistory(MockStateFixture mockStateFixture)
        {
            this.mockStateFixture = mockStateFixture;
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task Should_NotThrowHttpRequestException_When_AMessageHistoryIsCreated()
        {
            var recipients = MockMessage.GetRecipients("Acc", "Site 1", "Site 2", "Site 3");
            var message = MockMessage.GetMessage(recipients);

            mockStateFixture
                .MockMessageHistoryService
                .Setup(service => service.CreateMessageHistoryAsync(message));

            var messageHistoryService = new MessageHistoryService(
                mockStateFixture.MockIHttpClientFactory.Object);

            mockStateFixture.MockIHttpClientFactory.Object.CreateClient("CouchDB");

            var task = messageHistoryService.CreateMessageHistoryAsync(message);
            var type = task.GetType();
            Assert.True(type.GetGenericArguments()[0].Name == "VoidTaskResult");
            Assert.True(type.BaseType == typeof(Task));
            await task;

            //await Assert.IsType<Task>(messageHistoryService.CreateMessageHistoryAsync(message));
            // await Assert.ThrowsAsync<HttpRequestException>(() => messageHistoryService.CreateMessageHistoryAsync(message));
        }
    }
```

it seems to me that I also need to mock the CreateClient class is it?

Comment: Where do a the separate class where you're mocking? We need to see what you're doing in that class. Please post the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should inject a mocked object for `ClientFactory` for which you have setup the `CreateClient` method.

```
// create the mock client
var httpClient = new Mock<IHttpClient>();

// setup method call for client
httpClient.Setup(x=>x.PutAsync(It.IsAny<string>()
                               , It.IsAny<Message>(),
                               , It.IsAny< JsonMediaTypeFormatter>())
          .Returns(Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = StatusCode.OK}));

// create the mock client factory mock
var httpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();

// setup the method call
httpClientFactoryMock.Setup(x=>x.CreateClient(NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB))
                     .Returns(httpClient);
```

Then you have to pass the `httpClientFactoryMock.Object` to the constructor:

```
var messageHistoryService = new MessageHistoryService(httpClientFactoryMock.Object);
```

**Update**

In order to unit test `HttpClient` since it hasn't any interface you should wrap it in way as it is described [here](https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/).

Specifically we have to arrange the http client as below:

```
// Mock the handler
var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

handlerMock.Protected()
// Setup the PROTECTED method to mock
           .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("PutAsync",
                                             ItExpr.IsAny<String>(),
                                             ItExpr.IsAny<Message>()
                                             ItExpr.IsAny<MediaTypeFormatter>())
// prepare the expected response of the mocked http call
           .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage()
           {
               StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
           })
           .Verifiable();

// use real http client with mocked handler here
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handlerMock.Object)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://test.com/"),
};
```

Now we should return the above `httpClient` when `CreateClient` is called.

```
// create the mock client factory mock
var httpClientFactoryMock = new Mock<IHttpClientFactory>();

// setup the method call
httpClientFactoryMock.Setup(x=>x.CreateClient(NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB))
                     .Returns(httpClient);
```

Comment: There is no IHttpClient, just HttpClient, is that a typo? 

I changed it to HttpClient but the where part //setup the method call gives an error of cannot convert "Moq.Mock<System.Net.Http.HttpClient> to 'System.Net.HttpClient"

Comment: @IvanApungan I mistaken that your client implements an interface and it's the actual `HttpClient`. Please check my update. The link there will guide you in how you will mock the http client. So you should change from the above only this and make the httpClientFactory to return this. If something is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: You sir are a legend! Thank you very much!

Comment: @IvanApungan You are very welcome ! I am glad that I helped :)

Comment: @Christos you should update your answer with the proper HttpClient and message handler example since there is no IHttpClient.

Comment: @Nkosi Updated, if you thing that something is missing or is not clear, please let me know. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the IHttpMessageHandler has changed since the accepted answer.  In .NET6 it has 2 methods "Send" and "SendAsync".  So I've modified what @Christos did above and put it into a static class for reusability.

```
public static class MockHttpMessageHandler
{
    public static Mock<HttpMessageHandler> GetMessageHander(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        var handlerMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

        handlerMock.Protected()
            .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .ReturnsAsync(response)
            .Verifiable();

        handlerMock.Protected()
            .Setup<HttpResponseMessage>("Send", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
            .Returns(response)
            .Verifiable();

        return handlerMock;
    }
}
```

Usage is pretty simple, instead of creating a Mock, just instantiate this object directly:

```
[Test]
public void Http_Get_Async_Was_Called()
{
    // Arrange
    var fakeResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(P24LocationTestCaseData.StringData),
    };
    var httpMessageHandlerMock = MockHttpMessageHandler.GetMessageHander(fakeResponse);
    var httpClientMock = new Mock<HttpClient>(httpMessageHandlerMock.Object);

    // Act
    // Use your httpClientMock here

    // Assert
    // Check that the HttpClient SendAsync was called once
    httpMessageHandlerMock
        .Protected()
        .Verify("SendAsync", Times.Once(), ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>());
}
```

My implementation above is obviously returning a string and responding to any method (GET, POST, PUT, etc...) but you could modify it if you need to be specific.